# Save attachments

Tags: gnus, attachment

I'm trying to simply save attachments in Gnus.

I've read this: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual///html_node/mh-e/Viewing-Attachments.html and, I don't have `mm-decode` installed. For some reason Gnus is trying to use Emacs to open PDF files when I press <kbd>RET</kbd> on them.

I've searched the help buffer for anything related to attachments / article parts / w/e other names I can imagine Gnus may give to attachments, but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, nevermind, it's <kbd>o</kbd>. Or `gnus-mime-save-part`

Comment: You can accept your own answer FYI.